# Toggling dark/light theme in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes

How can i add a theme toggle function to my html/css website so it changes the theme to dark and light/white in a button? I understand there's a bit of .js involved...

I got a code from [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-dark-mode-on-the-web/#toggling-themes) and just coppied it, of course. But, I fail to make some of the text font colors change along with the rest of the fonts in the html. Can anyone assist because I even tried calling out the text classes themselves in the css query but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you are still having difficulty, provide your code

Comment: What part in your code do you need help with, please provide your approach.